# How can I figure out which QTimer is producing the message "Timers cannot be stopped from another thread"?

Tags: qt, debugging, qtimer

I'm working on a Qt app that creates a lot of threads and QTimers. When it exits, I get the following message printed:

```
2022-09-27 13:40:22.123 QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
2022-09-27 13:40:22.123 QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

So somewhere in my app, there's a bug where a QTimer is not being stopped properly when the app shuts down, and instead it's getting stopped when its object is automatically destroyed.

Given there's *a lot* of QTimers in my app, is there some way I can figure out which one is throwing this message? I'd like a better method than laboriously commenting out each QTimer in my app until the message goes away!

(I'm using Qt Creator on macOS to develop and debug the app.)

Comment: Try installing your own [message handler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler).  Then run under a debugger to get the backtrace when the handler is called with the message of interest.

Comment: @G.M. I actually did have my own message handler installed, but forgot I was removing it before my app quit. So I was able to use that to figure out which timer was causing the problem like you suggested. If you rewrite your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct.